# How to set Max of two values to an pixel?

Tags: c#, .net

i have used the following code butt geting error at Dimage.SetPixel "Dimage takes two arguments butt one is given to it"  its dilation code for an image.

```
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (path == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please load an image");
            return;
        }
        System.Drawing.Bitmap imageX = new Bitmap(pb1.Image);
        System.Drawing.Bitmap image = AForge.Imaging.Image.Clone
            (imageX, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        ConservativeSmoothing filterX = new ConservativeSmoothing();
        filterX.ApplyInPlace(image);
        Grayscale filter = new Grayscale(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
        Bitmap grayImage = filter.Apply(image);
        int temp;
        var imW = image.Width;
        var imH = image.Height;
        Bitmap Dimage = grayImage;
        for (int i = 1; i <= imW; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 2; j <= imH-1; j++)
            {
             temp = Math.Max(Convert.ToInt32(grayImage.GetPixel(i, j - 1)), Convert.ToInt32(grayImage.GetPixel(i, j)));
             Dimage.SetPixel(i,j) = Math.Max(temp, Convert.ToInt32(grayImage.GetPixel(i, j + 1)));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetPixel expects 3 parameters: x, y, color . You are only giving it two parameters and then using the third in an unusual way. Sorry for the pun, you should insert your Max result into the parentheses of SetPixel.